# How to open .jpg attachments in Whatsapp on android?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

When images are sent as .jpg attachment in WhatsApp on android, they are not displayed and I get the error

> "you may not have a proper app for viewing this content"

even though I can open .jpg files with my default gallery viewer app.

I noticed however that under `WhatsApp>Media>WhatsApp Documents` it is stored as **12345.jpg.enc** and wonder if that is the reason why (encryption?).

Any way to make the gallery viewer the default app for .enc?

Comment: Who did you receive the file from? Can they help? `.enc` could indeed represent some form of Encryption / Encoding, but we can't help you without more information...

Comment: It maybe means "enclosure" as a generic wrapper to hold multiple types of files within WhatsApp. You might just experiment by deleting the .enc and trying to view again. If it doesn't work what would be the harm to restore the extension again?

Comment: Sure they can but I have seen this happening before, hence I was wondering why this might happen. Need to see if I can find this myself.

Comment: @wbogacz, I can open the file in the filemanager as it gives the "Select open mode" option to use the image viewer. I want it to open when clicking it inside WhatsApp for a more native experience :) I thought it may have been WhatsApp that transfers .jpg files as .enc but maybe not.

Comment: If a straight  view is possible once directed, without decrypting (since how would the viewer do that autonomously?), it supports the wrapper theory.